# There's no way to link to comments on articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, articles

I just tried to get a link to one of the comments that were added to an article but I noticed that the comment timestamp is not clickable:

[image: Timestamp of articles' comments is not clickable]

Then, I tried to construct the URL myself by getting the comment id. I got the id and the URL should be:

> https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android#comment120398784_68104924

Or the short URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120398784

Although both URLs open the article page as expected, they do *not* redirect to the comment as with regular posts.

Comment: I think it may be the same functionality as comments on an election nomination. If you try the both methods on an election nomination post, it will just redirect you to the actual post, as seen here.

Comment: That's for pointing this out, we'll look into it and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting that.

Comments on Articles are a brand new thing, so some of the piping to make it all work as the other comments on the site was still missing. The deeplinking should be working now

Comment: Thanks for the fix. The comment timestamp is indeed now clickable and the link works. Short links still don't work though (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68475140/faster-cloud-storage-transfers-using-the-gcloud-command-line#comment121171885_68475140) works but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121171885) does not). I think this is worth implementing since short links are sometimes important (e.g., because of comments max-length) and also to be consistent with regular posts.

Comment: @41686d6564 Agreed. I'll take a look

Comment: @41686d6564 Short links should work now

Comment: Great! I actually noticed earlier today that the short links are used in the timeline (but still didn't jump to the anchor) and was going to come back here to comment about that but you were quicker than me :-) Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @41686d6564 My absolute favorite deadline to aim for: Right before someone complains I haven't done it yet! 